# jQuery adding more and more items onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that I want to add a list of my GitHub repos. I have it working, the only problem is that with every click, it appends the same list of repos to the list. Here is the code for the function

```html
<button onclick="loadRepos()" class="btn btn-warning justify-content-center">Load Repos from Github</button>
```

```js
function loadRepos(){
    let gitHubRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let gitObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (let i = 0; i < gitObject.length; i++){
            let ul = document.getElementById("repositories");
            let li = document.createElement("LI");
            li.className = "list-group-item";
            let a = document.createElement("a");

            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(gitObject[i].name));
            a.appendChild(li);
            a.setAttribute("href",gitObject[i].html_url);
            ul.appendChild(a);
        }
```

How can I make the button stop adding after it is clicked once. The end goal being it shows the list when you click it, then hides the list when clicked again. I tried to use .toggle, but couldn't make it work. any suggestions? thanks in advance everyone :)

Comment: For starters you don't need to make the gitHubRequest on every click, just the first click.  On subsequent clicks it should just be a matter of toggling, but you will need to keep track of how many clicks, odd or even, show on one, hide on the other.  You will probably be advised to do this with a global variable and I would disagree with that, there's a better way, but it would work.  Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I actually thought of the odd/even trick after I posted. If I get the solution working I will post it. It may not be the prettiest, but it will work haha.

Comment: @OleTuck jokes aside on that other question you had. You want to google webscraping. You can get the contents of a webpage there, and then do all that other stuff you asked about - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/

Answer (score 1):

Loading every time on click just for the sake of hidding and showing data is wastefull, rather just load your data once and use the click event to hide and show this data;

```
function loadRepos(){
    let gitHubRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    gitHubRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let gitObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let ul = document.getElementById("repositories");
            for (let i = 0; i < gitObject.length; i++){

                let li = document.createElement("LI");
                li.className = "list-group-item";
                let a = document.createElement("a");

                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(gitObject[i].name));
                a.appendChild(li);
                a.setAttribute("href",gitObject[i].html_url);
                ul.appendChild(a);
            }
        }
    }
}

loadRepos();

function toggleRepositories() {
    document.getElementById("repositories").classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="toggleRepositories()" class="btn btn-warning justify-content-center">Load Repos from Github</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```